# Permuting the formula argument to Hmisc:aregImpute

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, regression-strategies

In Frank Harrell's [RMS Short Course](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RmS) today, I became aware that multiple imputation with `Hmisc:aregImpute` is not invariant to the ordering of terms in its formula argument, and that one therefore ought to check results of imputation under permutations of these terms. Here's a simple function that generates the necessary permutations:

```
perms <- function(n, formula) {
    rhs <- attr(terms(formula), 'term.labels')
    formulae <- list()
    for(i in 1:n){
        formulae[[i]] <- as.formula(paste("~", paste(sample(rhs), collapse="+")))
    }
    formulae
}
```

For example:

```
> perms(5, ~ age + sex + bp + death + mi)
[[1]]
~mi + age + bp + sex + death
<environment: 0x10dc9cbb8>

[[2]]
~bp + mi + sex + age + death
<environment: 0x10dc9cbb8>

[[3]]
~mi + bp + age + death + sex
<environment: 0x10dc9cbb8>

[[4]]
~age + death + bp + sex + mi
<environment: 0x10dc9cbb8>

[[5]]
~bp + age + death + sex + mi
<environment: 0x10dc9cbb8>

>
```

This could be used with `lapply` as follows:

```
as <- lapply(perms(5, ~ age + sex + bp + death + mi)
             , aregImpute, data=mydata, n.impute=10)
```

But I wonder whether it might make more sense to incorporate this into aregImpute itself.

Comment: Thanks for the nice contribution.  If I don't put this inside `aregImpute` I can at least put this as an example in the help file.  Nice work.  It is important to check the algorithm to see if the final inference depends on the order of variables, when more than one variable is missing on the same subject.  Another way to get variable names from a simple formula is `all.vars(formula)`.